# Why color appears as HTML attribute on a div?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

This code works perfectly, it creates CSS classes with the corresponding color and applies the classes dynamically:

```
const Div = styled.div`
    color: ${({ color }) => color};
`;

export default function Email() {
    const [color, changeColor] = useState();

    return (
        <>
            <Div color={color}>Email</Div>
            {['red', 'palevioletred', 'blue', 'yellow'].map(x => <button onClick={() => changeColor(x)}>{x}</button>)}
        </>
    )
}
```

However, the `color` attribute appears in the DOM on the `div` element:

```
<div class="sc-crHlIS jxntNS" color="yellow">Email</div>
```

When I change the `color` prop name to something else like `divColor` it doesn't show as a DOM attribute. I understand that props appear as HTML attributes when they have the same name as a native HTML attribute, but `color` should not because it's not a valid HTML attribute.

Why this behavior?

Comment: While technically not valid browsers don't seem to care. Before `data-` attributes came along using custom attributes was not uncommon. I wouldn't worry about it. Attributes used in frameworks like Angular and Vue have all kinds of funky stuff in them

Comment: I don't really worry, this just looks illogical to me. I like React for producing clean HTML (compared to Angular selectors for example) and I wonder if I'm missing something or if it's just a bug of this library.

Comment: Bug or convenience? I haven't used that lib for long time but seems like it could be helpful when inspecting elements. Doubt it's a bug

Comment: Good question, my actual question :p

Comment: what does it do with something like `text-decoration:underline`? Or perhaps `textDecoration:underline`

Comment: I just tested it and it also appears as HTML attribute, so I guess all of the props with a valid CSS name appear as HTML attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Styled components](https://styled-components.com/) has a set of HTML attributes that it allows to be passed down to the resulting element. The `color` attribute is not technically valid for a `div` element, however it *is* a HTML attribute, and this is the criteria it follows.

From [the docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props):

> If the styled target is a simple element (e.g. styled.div), styled-components passes through any known HTML attribute to the DOM. If it is a custom React component (e.g. styled(MyComponent)), styled-components passes through all props.

The documentation does not explicitly state that they accept *any* attribute on any element, however it seems to be the case given this example:

```
<Div color="red" foo="foo" value="value" name="name" bar="bar">My div</Div>
```

Results in:

```
<div color="red" value="value" name="name">My div</div>
```

Notice how the non HTML attributes are removed, but the others remain.

Comment: What's the exact rule? Valid HTML and CSS attributes? *The color attribute is not technically valid for a div element* this is true then why does it appear?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a quote from the official docs. I'm not sure what you mean by "CSS attributes" - do you mean the `style` attribute?

Comment: I mean that `color` is invalid as an HTML attribute, but valid as a CSS property

Comment: The `color` attribute is a valid HTML attribute, belonging to the `font` tag.

Comment: Indeed `'color' in HTMLFontElement.prototype === true` does that mean that all of the valid HTML attributes appear regardless of the actual element?

Comment: Their documentation does not explicitly state that, however it seems to be the case given the example above.

Comment: Can you add this precision to your answer so I can mark it as accepted?